# Checking if TableView row was selected for the first time

Tags: swift

I have added one row in TableView. I want after app updating there was a red marker on this row so user could see what exactly was added. After first selecting this row after updating marker should dismiss. 
How can I check if user selected new row for the first time?

Comment: Charlie Fish, actually nothing. All I could find is how to check first launch of app. But user may not open new row while first launch.

Comment: I would encourage you to read the help center before posting. Stack Overflow is meant for a last resort after trying all other resources and putting a considerable amount of effort into the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a set like this.

```
var selectedOnce = Set<Int>()
```

Add the selected index to this set whenever it is selected first time.

```
selectedOnce.insert(index)
```

Check next time, whether it was already selected like

```
        if selectedOnce.contains(indexToCheck) {

}
```

If something is required for one time per app. I mean, it should not happen for next launches of the app you can use user defaults. Set the key to true for first time

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadyClicked")
```

Check for the key to know whether something user has already done in previous launches like this

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "alreadyClicked") {

}
```

User defaults persist between app launches. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about something like this. But while next app running wouldn't set became empty again? Or is it possible to save it's value for every next running?

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot.